# With proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation I got " Argument 2 passed to must be of the type array" under Windows php7.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

I added proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation to my laravel 6 app which works ok on my
ubuntu 18 with PHP 7.2.24
But My client pulling the version got error on his Windows / php 7.4.2 as :

```
#57 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\primewatch\\public\\index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#58 {main}

[previous exception] [object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Argument 2 passed to Proengsoft\\JsValidation\\JsValidatorFactory::__construct() must be of the type array, null given, called in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\primewatch\\vendor\\proengsoft\\laravel-jsvalidation\\src\\JsValidationServiceProvider.php on line 38 at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\primewatch\\vendor\\proengsoft\\laravel-jsvalidation\\src\\JsValidatorFactory.php:37)
[stacktrace]
#0 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\primewatch\\vendor\\proengsoft\\laravel-jsvalidation\\src\\JsValidationServiceProvider.php(38): Proengsoft\\JsValidation\\JsValidatorFactory->__construct(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), NULL)
#1 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\primewatch\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(799): Proengsoft\\JsValidation\\JsValidationServiceProvider->Proengsoft\\JsValidation\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array)
#2 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\primewatch\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(681): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build(Object(Closure))
#3 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\primewatch\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application.php(785): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve('jsvalidator', Array, true)
#4 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\primewatch\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(629): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->resolve('jsvalidator', Array)
#5 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\primewatch\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application.php(770): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make('jsvalidator', Array)
#6 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\primewatch\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(1245): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make('jsvalidator')
#7 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\primewatch\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade.php(198): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->offsetGet('jsvalidator')
#8 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\primewatch\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade.php(166): Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade::resolveFacadeInstance('jsvalidator')
#9 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\primewatch\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade.php(255): Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade::getFacadeRoot()
#10 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\primewatch\\storage\\framework\\views\\68757a9c9b2f658eb9358cc98549740ca7f9e23d.php(34): Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade::__callStatic('formRequest', Array)
#11 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\primewatch\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\PhpEngine.php(43): include('C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs...')
#12 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\primewatch\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\CompilerEngine.php(59): Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\PhpEngine->evaluatePath('C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs...', Array)
#13 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\primewatch\\vendor\\facade\\ignition\\src\\Views\\Engines\\CompilerEngine.php(36): Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\CompilerEngine->get('C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs...', Array)
#14 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\primewatch\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\View\\View.php(143): Facade\\Ignition\\Views\\Engines\\CompilerEngine->get('C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs...', Array)
```

I have app/Http/Requests/ShipRequest.php with :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Traits\funcsTrait;

use App\Ship;

class ShipRequest extends FormRequest
{
    use funcsTrait;
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        $request= Request();
        return Ship::getValidationRulesArray( $request->get('id') );
    }

}
```

And in Ship Model method getValidationRulesArray is defined as :

```
public static function getValidationRulesArray($ship_id= null) : array
{
    $validationRulesArray = [
        'title' => [
            'required',
            'string',
            'max:255',
            Rule::unique(with(new Ship)->getTable())->ignore($ship_id),
        ],
        'company_id'      => 'required|exists:' . ( with(new Company)->getTable() ).',id',
    ];
    return $validationRulesArray;
}
```

I wonder why such error on Windows/php 7.4. Can it be php different issue or what ?

```
"laravel/framework": "^6.2",
"proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation": "^2.5",
```

Thanks!

Comment: looks like the config file config/jsvalidation.php is missing in your client's machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure use JsValidatorFacade not JsValidatorFactory

you can use this syntac
use Proengsoft\JsValidation\Facades\JsValidatorFacade as JsValidator;

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, all you need is to run following command

```
php artisan config:cache
```

because validator is not loading the jsvalidation config file just created in config directory

Hope it helps somebody.